# Flutter - How to stop a periodic timer from outside the timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I have a flutter app in which I am simply opening a webview and am receiving messages via the javascript channel from the website. Now based on messages received from the website I have to start a periodic timer and stop (cancel) the timer on another message as well. As far as I can research I am just being allowed to cancel from within the timer or from dispose if the timer was initialized in initstate.
Here is my code right now -

```
JavascriptChannel _lightVibrationJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
return JavascriptChannel(
    name: 'x',
    onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
      var pattern = json.decode(message.message);
      if (pattern["eventName"] == "start") {
        //Make Periodic Timer
      } else if (pattern["eventName"] == "stop") {
        //Stop Periodic Timer
      }
    });
}
```

If I am making a global timer and initializing it at the time of making the periodic timer it will obviously not allow me to cancel it from within the else condition. I am bit lost. Any help?

Comment: Can't you just use a class-scoped `Timer? timer` variable and store youre `timer = Timer.periodic(...)` and use `timer?.cancel`. I dont see a reason why it "would not allow you to cancel it from within the else"?

Comment: Damn, what a brainfart. Wasn't checking the nullable condition when I did that. Thanks.